# Applying Colours Scheme to Gnome 3.14 Terminal

Tags: colors, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to change the colour scheme on my gnome terminal running on debian jessie. I've tried different ways, like [Base16 Builder](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-builder) or [Base16 Gnome Terminal](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-gnome-terminal), but none seem to work. After I generate the theme and run the script to apply it, nothing happenes - no new profile is created and no colour is changed.

Does anyone have any suggestion for how I could apply one of these themes?

Comment: It should work (well, one of the scripts randomly from [Base16 Gnome Terminal](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-gnome-terminal) worked for me on Ubuntu Vivid). You could try to debug that script step-by-step. Make sure that the necessary utilities (e.g. `dconf`, `uuidgen`) are installed. The script should enter the first branch: "Newest versions of gnome-terminal use dconf". You can open dconf-editor in the mean time and navigate to org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.profiles and watch for a new profile toappear.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and select *Edit* -> *Profile Preferences* -> *Colors* tab -> uncheck *Use colors from system theme*.

The only color customization in the below screenshot is to change the text color to white and the background color to black, like in the Windows cmd window, to improve readability. If you are accustomed to using the Windows command line, you should give this color scheme a try.

[image]

Comment: This *looks* plausible, but as a one line answer, it got flagged as low quality. Could you add a screenshot, or a little more detail, to up the awesomeness quotient of your answer?